# Segfault and incorrect output in multithreaded application

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm learning multithreading in C, and have some troubles understanding why my code doesn't give the expected output and segfaults. I'm using the pthread library in C and my code starts a total of m*2 threads, m for each of the two functions it starts. The first function calculates a 30 random numbers and stores it in a global array. The second function then reads the integers from the array, calculates their sum and their average. The second thread also waits for the first thread with pthread_join, but it seems to join sometimes before the first thread exits.

What am I doing wrong here?

I'm also aware using mutexes would be a much better option, but I'm trying to this without mutexes on purpose.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int n = 30;
int arr[100][30];

pthread_t tfirst[100];
pthread_t tsecond[100];


void *first(void *x){

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        arr[(int)x][i] = rand();

}

void *second(void *x){
    pthread_join(tfirst[(int)x], NULL);

    long sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        sum += arr[(int)x][n];
    }

    printf("Sum %d = %ld\n", (int)x + 1, sum);
    sleep(1);
    printf("Arithmetic mean %d = %f\n", (int)x + 1, (float)sum / n);
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int m;
    srand(time(0));
    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s m [n]", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    m = atoi(argv[1]);
    if(argc >= 3) n = atoi(argv[2]);


    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        if (pthread_create(&tfirst[i], NULL, first, (void*)i)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (pthread_create(&tsecond[i], NULL, second, (void*)i)) {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread!\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }



    }
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        pthread_join(tfirst[i], NULL);
        pthread_join(tsecond[i], NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You call `pthread_join(tfirst` twice - first inside of thread2 routine and then at the end of mine.

Comment: Thank you, removing that line solved the segfault (even though the program output is still incorrect). However, I still don't fully understand why did the pthread_join cause a segfault. In the man page, it says " If that thread has  already  terminated,  then  pthread_join() returns immediately", which led me to believe there is no harm in calling pthread_join twice.

Comment: What do you mean by "output is still incorrect"?

Comment: Well, each tfirst thread stores 30 pseudorandom integers in an array. After the execution of the first function, the second function should calculate the sum and the average of the numbers stored by tfirst. However, the output is often 0 for the sum. As Andriy said, this could be because the second thread, tsecond might actually start before the relevant tfirst thread even starts execution.

I also tried spawning the second thread at the end of the first function, but that lead to additional segfaults and the output is still incorrect.

Comment: Even if `second` thread starts before corresponding `first` thread calling `pthread_join` at the beginning of second thread will make it wait for first thread to fill the array.

Comment: I tried adding a `pthread_create` at the end of the `first` function and `pthread_join` at the start of the `second` function, but the code still occasionally segfaults and outputs a zero for the sum. 
I'm now also spawning only the `second` thread in the `main` function.

Comment: There is no need for such changes, removing `pthread_join(tfirst[i], NULL);` from main should be sufficient. You should not try changing code randomly hoping that one variant is going to work.

Comment: What value do you enter for n?   If it's 30, you have a problem.

Comment: Show inputs and outputs.

Comment: The output by just removing that single `pthread_join(tfirst[i], NULL)` in main:
`Sum 2 = 0
Sum 1 = 259125030
Sum 4 = 0
Sum 3 = 54542150670
Arithmetic mean 2 = 0.000000
Arithmetic mean 3 = 1818071680.000000
Arithmetic mean 1 = 8637501.000000
Arithmetic mean 4 = 0.000000`

And yes, the value for n is 30. 
I'm not changing the code randomly, I'm trying to understand why it doesn't produce the expected output.

Comment: In fact, if you don't enter any value for n, you have a problem since the default is 30.

Comment: [30] is an out-of-bounds index.

Comment: Martin, why would that be a problem? It never goes to 30.

Comment: Because reading out of bounds is UB and sum calculating code does not work.

Comment: Specifically here: 'sum += arr[(int)x][n];'

Comment: Wait a second, where is my code fetching out of bounds values? The for loops go up to `strictly less than` 30, which is 29. The same thing happens for lower values of n, such as 10.

Comment: Every 'second' thread instance uses [n] as the second index of the array.  The same value of 'n' for each. I don't think that is what you intended and, for n=30, is an out-of-bounds read.

Comment: Did you mean 'sum += arr[(int)x][i];'  and put 'n' by mistake?

Comment: Oh my god, how did I miss that? I meant to write `arr[(int)x][i]`. Thank you, I can't believe I didn't see that! I lost so much time on that, I just couldn't figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Zorg oh it's easy, especially if you use single-letter var names, (ie protip - don't use single-letter var names!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You call `pthread_join` twice for the same thread - first inside of `second` thread routine and then at the end of `main`.

From [`pthread_join` reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html#):

> The results of multiple simultaneous calls to pthread_join() specifying the same target thread are undefined.
>
> The behavior is undefined if the value specified by the thread argument to pthread_join() does not refer to a joinable thread.

The part *"If that thread has already terminated, then pthread_join() returns immediately"* means that calling `pthread_join` on the thread that already ended (but is still joinable) makes call return immediately, however after this call thread is not joinable anymore and calling `pthread_join` again will result an UB.

Your sum calculation code is wrong: `sum += arr[(int)x][n];` will only use the `n`th value (that is out of bounds which leads to UB as well).

Also both thread routines should return a value: `return NULL;`

Answer (score 1):

> The second thread also waits for the first thread with pthread_join, but it seems to join sometimes before the first thread exits.

Actually, second thread could start execution even before the first thread. There are no guarantees whatsoever regarding thread execution order.

The solution would be to use just one thread, i.e. at the ent of the `firts()` just call `second()`. This will guarantee the execution order between those functions without any mutexes.

Comment: Yes, or start the second thread from the first, once the array is fully initialized.  Yes - horribly inefficient overall, but it's obviously just an exercise anyway since averaging 30 numbers is hugely trivial for threading off, so who cares? :)